# Multiple .NET apps within tabbed app

Tags: asp.net, .net, tabs, webforms

We have several fairly large ASP.NET web projects that we've been asked to combine under one, tabbed interface.  So, for example, when you click tab 1, we would show project A underneath.  Then if you click on tab 2, we would show project B.  I'm referring below to each project as an "app" because they perform different functions for our users.

Does anyone have a good way to do this?  One key problem here is that each app must remember state.  So if the user is halfway through filling out a web form on App A/tab 1, then they click on another tab to do some work for a bit, when they come back to app A/tab 1 they should see their half-completed form (which is not yet saved to database).

We've discussed several options:  iframes might be a possibility, but we're afraid to commit to those because they may be falling out of favor and they can having resizing and printing issues. We don't think we can simply embed each app in a  and hide/show it as you click between tabs, because the size of the page would grow very large if you have alot of tabs open and we would have issues when a .NET app/page triggers a postback (many of our apps use tradition .net postbacks).

In some ways, we're essentially being asked to write a browser that has a .net app in each tab.  We can't actually use a browser to do this because we cannot force a browser to open a new tab (versus a separate window).

Does anyone have any ideas of how to "wrap" multiple .NET apps into one tabbed UI? Or is this simply impossible?  Or is it wrong to write off iframe solution?  Each .net project could be presented in an iframe which is simply hidden when not visible?

Thanks.

Comment: which technology ? Winform/wpf ?

Comment: Would a winforms app with a tab control and WebBrowser controls work?

Comment: These are ASP.NET webform projects.  Each performs a specific function, that's why I referred to as an app.  This is for a financial firm, so one "app" might provide transaction information, another might provide stock market research.  All perform .NET page postbacks.

Comment: You might wanna look into enterprise portals solutions, i know there are few that allow multiple sites to run within a portal.

Comment: @OP can you update tags to include asp.net, asp.net webforms

Answer (score 0):

In projects I've worked on a custom MVC framework was developed. Inside the tab you would have a controller for each  tab(application). The data would be persisted in the the shared view using a viewstate or the model used for each application.

Comment: Could you give me some more details on that?? How would you grab the state of each page before you leave it (so it can be presented again later)?

Comment: @user1308260 When working on the tabbed page you are not actually leaving you are just changing the controls that are visible. You appear to leave from the user end but you are still within the same form. The only time that changes you user has mad will be lost is when the refresh()/reload() method is called and of course  when closing the form. This is because all the controls are bound to using a bindingSource who's datasource is a model. This model is fetched  during refresh from the controller and has no chance of affecting the database until is saved.

Comment: @user1308260 the view would only contain a new controller instance , bindingsource, model, and your controls. all logic is in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

- Modify existing WPF/WinForms applications so that the Main Window contains
  nothing but one user control. All application logic should be
  contained within the user control or elements contained in the user
  control.
- Create a "shell" application that holds an assembly reference to your other applications.
- Put the user controls that serve as the "Main" screen into the tabs. You can use a `WindowsFormsHost` to host your Windows Forms controls in a WPF application (or vice versa using `ElementHost`).

The problem that remains are dialogs that have to retain state, this could pose a problem when changing tabs.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified better in my initial post that these are .NET webform projects (not win apps).

Comment: this is web based app according to OP, he is talking about iframes and browsers

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
create a custom server control for the "tabs" and reference it in each of the apps that you want to navigate to with the tabs.  You will have full control over the tab "clicking" events in each app so that you can save state.  Each app can be its own website if it needs to be or just deployed as virtual dirs on the same site.

I would probably pull the tab configuration out of the code and put it in a config file or db so that you can add and subtract apps from the tab UI without recompiling and redeploying the tab control.

**Option 2**
Create a "master page" and then have javascript in the page to hide and show iframes with each application in them.  You can use javascript to make sure the iframe is always maximized to the content size.  With iframes you don't have to worry about state since it would all be in the browser at the same time.

Possible issues:

1. timeouts, if an application is hidden and isn't getting input, will it timeout?
2. Cross domain scripting if they aren't all on the same domain
3. Printing might require a custom coded solution depending on how you want it to look

Comment: so you're saying that when user clicks tab, each app would have to save it's own state?  wouldn't that be difficult to save half entered forms - each one that has different properties/fields? Or is there any way to generically save the entire contents of any web form?  Thanks for your idea.

Comment: I assumed you had control of the application code.  I don't see how you can maintain the application state without that control.

Comment: Though I would prefer to not have to rewrite the code, I do have control over it.  Can you tell me how an app would save state when that state would be different on many different web forms?  For example, one page might have filtered data on it based on a drop down selection.  Another page might be more a typical web form with entry fields/boxes to fill in text data.  Wouldn't each have to be "hardcoded" to save the data entered before leaving? And if so, woudln't that be a huge undertaking?  Maybe you're saying that's what I have to do.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it is possibly big.  You need to save your user's not finished work to the db so that they come back later and finish it.

Comment: The iframe idea is by far the most attractive since it requires the least amount of code changes and should allow for postbacks and state. But I had heard iframes might be phasing out of existence. If anyone has any knowledge about that, please share.  Thanks again for the ideas.

Comment: I've never heard anything about them being phased out.  There are plenty of reasons they lost "favor" because they were used to make very bad behaving web sites.  But there are many, many ways they are still useful.